# Container of pointers to template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, containers

I'm trying to make a class (`ParametersHolder`) that can contain different named parameters (`Parameter<T>`). The `ParametersHolder` has an `std::unordered_map` container holding my parameters. To make this work, I had to derive `Parameter<T>` from an empty `ParameterBase` class and I dynamically cast `ParameterBase` to `Parameter<T>` when I want to get a parameter with the right type. Here is the code:

**ParametersHolder.hpp**

```
...
#include "Parameter.hpp"

class ParametersHolder {

  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ParameterBase>> parameters;

  public:

    bool paramExists(std::string name) {
      return parameters.find(name) != parameters.end();
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter<T>> getOrCreate(std::string name, int dims = 1) {
      if (paramExists(name)) {
        return getParam<T>(name);
      }
      return create<T>(name, dims);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter<T>> create(std::string name, int dims = 1) {
      if (paramExists(name)) throw std::runtime_error("Trying to create parameter '" + name + "' but it already exists");
      auto param = std::make_shared<Parameter<T>>(dims);
      parameters[name] = param;
      return param;
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter<T>> getParam(std::string name) {
      if (!paramExists(name)) throw std::runtime_error("Parameter '" + name + "' doesn't exist");
      auto param = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Parameter<T>>(parameters[name]);
      if (param == nullptr) throw std::runtime_error("Parameter '" + name + "' is not a(n) " + boost::typeindex::type_id<T>().pretty_name());
      return param;
    }

};
```

**Parameter.hpp**

```
class ParameterBase {
  public:
    virtual ~ParameterBase() {}
};

template<typename T>
class Parameter : public ParameterBase {

  std::vector<T> data;

  public:

    explicit Parameter(int dim = 1) : data(dim) {}

    T getValue(int dim = 1) {
      dimCheck(dim);
      return data[dim - 1];
    }

    void setValue(T value, int dim = 1) {
      dimCheck(dim);
      data[dim - 1] = value;
    }

  private:
    void dimCheck(int dim) {
      if (dim > data.size()) {
        auto errorMsg = "Trying to access dimension " + std::to_string(dim)
          + " but parameter has only " + std::to_string(data.size()) + " dimensions";

        throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg); 
      }
    }
};
```

To use this code I can do that:

```
auto paramsHolder = std::make_shared<ParametersHolder>();
auto filename = paramsHolder->create<std::string>("filename");
filename->setValue("untitled.txt");

...

auto param = paramsHolder->getParam<std::string>("filename");
std::cout << param->getValue() << std::endl;
```

This works fine but having an empty `ParameterBase` feels odd. Is there another way to achieve that? I read about `boost::any`, but I'm not sure this is the right use case. And if it is, I don't know what the type signature of the `unordered_map` should be among these:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Parameter<boost::any>>>
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<boost::any>>
std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any>
```

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of it by using `shared_ptr<void>`, `static_pointer_cast` and a static family identifier for the types, so that you know when the `T` used to create the pointer and the one used to get it differ.
A working example based on your own code is much better in this case:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class Parameter {
  std::vector<T> data;

  public:

    explicit Parameter(int dim = 1) : data(dim) {}

    T getValue(int dim = 1) {
      dimCheck(dim);
      return data[dim - 1];
    }

    void setValue(T value, int dim = 1) {
      dimCheck(dim);
      data[dim - 1] = value;
    }

  private:
    void dimCheck(int dim) {
      if (dim > data.size()) {
        auto errorMsg = "Trying to access dimension " + std::to_string(dim)
          + " but parameter has only " + std::to_string(data.size()) + " dimensions";

        throw std::runtime_error(errorMsg); 
      }
    }
};

class ParametersHolder {
  std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<std::size_t, std::shared_ptr<void>>> parameters;

  std::size_t next() {
      static std::size_t value = 0;
      return value++;
  }

  template<typename>
  std::size_t type() {
      static std::size_t value = next();
      return value;
  }

public:

    bool paramExists(std::string name) {
      return parameters.find(name) != parameters.end();
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter<T>> getOrCreate(std::string name, int dims = 1) {
      if (paramExists(name)) {
        return getParam<T>(name);
      }
      return create<T>(name, dims);
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter<T>> create(std::string name, int dims = 1) {
      if (paramExists(name)) throw std::runtime_error("Trying to create parameter '" + name + "' but it already exists");
      auto param = std::make_shared<Parameter<T>>(dims);
      parameters[name] = { type<T>(), param };
      return param;
    }

    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter<T>> getParam(std::string name) {
      if (!paramExists(name)) throw std::runtime_error("Parameter '" + name + "' doesn't exist");
      if (parameters[name].first != type<T>()) throw std::runtime_error("Parameter '" + name + "' is not a(n) " + std::to_string(type<T>()));
      auto param = std::static_pointer_cast<Parameter<T>>(parameters[name].second);
      return param;
    }
};

int main() {
     auto paramsHolder = std::make_shared<ParametersHolder>();
     auto filename = paramsHolder->create<std::string>("filename");
     filename->setValue("untitled.txt");

     auto param = paramsHolder->getParam<std::string>("filename");
     std::cout << param->getValue() << std::endl;
}
```

See it on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5eb5643858c04ff).